# Dónde colocar las consultas complejas usando el Patrón Repositorio

Tags: c#, entity-framework, patrones-de-diseño, arquitectura-de-software

Tengo una aplicación donde uso Entity Framework y tengo una clase llamada `BaseRepository<T>` con unos cuantos métodos básicos de CRUD, tales como (Get, GetAll, Update, Delete, Insert), y de esta clase genero mis repositorios específicos, tales como `BaseRepository<Products>`, `BaseRepository<Persons>`, `BaseRepository<Countries>` y muchos otros más.

El problema es que, cuando tengo una lógica compleja en el servicio que involucra hacer joins de varias tablas y que no retornan una entidad, sino un objeto DTO complejo con campos de distintas tablas, me encuentro con que los repositorios no me ayudan mucho con solo las operaciones básicas de CRUD.

Dónde debería colocar este query complejo? en cuál de los repositorios debe estar? cómo hago el join de estos repositorios?. El problema es que veo que los repositorios manejan una única entidad, qué debería hacer en este caso?. Estuve investigando y leí que retornar `IQueryable<T>` es una mala práctica, así que descarto enviar `IQueryable<T>` de las tablas que voy a joinear al servicio y hacerlo allí.

He investigado y no he encontrado una respuesta clara. Quisiera saber cómo y dónde se organizan estos queries complejos, ya que quiero respetar también la responsabilidad de cada repositorio con su respectiva entidad.

Comment: Intenta generar una vista sql y llamarla con tu BaseRepository aunque estas solo son para consulta.

Comment: ¿Un objeto que no es DTO? Es necesario que proporciones un ejemplo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Las preguntas basadas en opiniones no tienen una respuesta concreta y suelen terminar cerradas....

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tengo algo que podría ayudarte.
Tengo un proyecto en EF Core donde utilizo un repositorio genérico y los joins los hago a través del metodo Get. Adjunto codigo de como esta hecho el get:

```
        public virtual IEnumerable<T> Get(
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "",
            bool ignoreQueryFilters = false,
            bool tracking = true)
        {
        IQueryable<T> query = tracking ? this.Entities : this.Entities.AsNoTracking();

        if (ignoreQueryFilters)
        {
            query = query.IgnoreQueryFilters();
        }

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (string includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty.Trim());
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query);
        }
        else
        {
            return query;
        }
    }
```

Los joins los hago a través del parámetro includeProperties. Si en tu Clase PersonsModel del modelo de base de datos tienes una propiedad de tipo ICollection Products entonces en el servicio podrías llamarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
//Ejemplo propiedad clase
public virtual ICollection<ProductsModel> Products{ get; set; }
//Ejemplo como utilizar el get
var resultadoo = Get(x => x.DNI == "12312", includeProperties: "Products").ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

En includeproperties colocas el nombre de la propiedad ICollection entre comillas. En este caso Cuando haces el get te devuelve la persona y sus productos relacionados. (Los hago con expresiones lambda porque son muy fáciles de utilizar)
En mi caso mis repositorios están vacíos en cuanto a métodos. Ejemplo:

```
public class ProveedoresRepository : GenericRepository<ProveedoresModel>, IProveedoresRepository
{
    public ProveedoresRepository(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
    {

    }


}
```

De esta manera respeto el diseño y cada repositorio trabaja con su entidad. y Luego los llamo en el servicio y hago los respectivos joins si es necesario.

Nota: la manera en que utilizo IncludeProperties funciona en Entity Framework Core, no lo probe en Entity Framework común. Espero que te sirva, Saludos!